# How to make my fixed "mobile-nav" bar appear when I scroll down the page?

Tags: scroll, fixed, fade, nav

```css
#web-nav {
  display: none;
}
#mobile-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(img/menu-bg.png) repeat;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mobile-nav">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img class="logo" src="admin/wp-content/themes/mame/assets/img/sicklehammer.png" />
  </a>
  <img class="drop-nav" src="open.png" />
</nav>
<nav id="mobile-expand">
  <img class="logo" src="logo.png" />
  <img class="close" src="img/close.png" />
  <div id="hidden-nav">

  </div>

  <ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="work/index.html">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="blog/index.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ul class="work-subs">

      <li><a href="/index.html">Movies</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/index.html">Photos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: First of all, you can't put a `<ul>` directly inside another `<ul>`; if you truly want it to be "nested", put it within a pair of `<li>` tags....

Comment: Thanks. The designer of the template has already designed the template with some mistakes, but my knowledge about "coding" is poor. I'm afraid If I perform some "unwanted" changes If I do what you suggest. I wish I had someone inside me to get help from.

Comment: Sounds like you're just getting started with web development. You're going to need to learn a lot about Javascript, but without good HTML/CSS skills (even if the templating is supposed to be someone else's job), you're going to be lost. I've suggested this [tutorial](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/) to some people, who have found it very helpful. I think it's very well organized and explained, but doesn't cover Javascript. There are lots of resources for that, but I have none to recommend. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use

```html
<script> 
  $('#main-nav').hide();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 750) {
       $('#main-nav').fadeIn();
    } else {
       $('#main-nav').fadeOut();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where to paste this code? sorry but i am not familiar with java script codes.

Comment: Tumaj, if you're new to javascript, I think you'll be needing a lot more than this simple code snippet, so I'm afraid that "where to paste" it is out of the scope of your original question. :) Note also that @simon's solution depends on the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) library.

Comment: Add this code in the body of your page:
<script> $('#mobile-nav').hide();
                       $(window).scroll(function () {
                        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 750)
                        {
                            $('#mobile-nav').fadeIn();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#mobile-nav').fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
</script>

You'll also need to add jquery.min.js in the head of your page.

Comment: I have to agree with Lambart tho, if youre asking questions like this, you'll have a hard time setting everything up.